# Apache STORM - Moving file to a different location using hdfsbolt is not working

Tags: java, hdfs, apache-storm

I have following code where I am trying to move the file to a different location once the file rotation is complete. The MOVEFILEACTION is not happening (no errors either). Not sure if I am missing something here.

```
SyncPolicy syncPolicy = new CountSyncPolicy(100);

// Rotate data files when they reach five MB
FileRotationPolicy rotationPolicy = new FileSizeRotationPolicy(0.05f, Units.MB);

MoveFileAction moveFileAction = new MoveFileAction().toDestination(rootPath + "/test");

FileNameFormat fileNameFormat = new DefaultFileNameFormat()
                    .withPath(rootPath + "/staging")
                    .withPrefix(prefix);


// Instantiate the HdfsBolt
HdfsBolt hdfsBolt = new HdfsBolt()
             .withFsUrl(fsUrl)
             .withFileNameFormat(fileNameFormat)
             .withRecordFormat(format)
             .withRotationPolicy(rotationPolicy)
             .withSyncPolicy(syncPolicy)
             .addRotationAction(moveFileAction);
```

Comment: It was a simple mistake.. I did not create the /test directory in hdfs. Now its working as expected.